# No files displaying (.log and .jtl files) in jenkins Workspace post running a JMeter jmx script via jenkins?

Tags: jmeter, jenkins, jmeter-plugins, continuous-integration

Running a JMeter script via Jenkins with Performance plugin via Windows batch command as:

```
cd C:/apache-jmeter-4.0/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin
jmeter -n -t C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/JMeter/Suite.jmx -l Results.jtl
```

I have defined my source data file as **/*.jtl in test result report.

The build gets executed successfully but the Workspace is empty (No files in directory) ! Even without any post build action, when I run the build it gets executed successfully but there's nothing in Workspace!

I have my jmeter user.property file to change output format to xml

How do I fix it?

Also just a tad offtrack but I can't also see jmeter.log file anywhere in my jmeter folder. I want that to be there as well in Workspace along with Results.jtl file. Also would like to refresh the data on every build run don't want the stats to combine with the stats of the previous builds in a cumulative manner, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is because your first command is [cd](https://www.computerhope.com/cdhlp.htm) which stands for `Change Directory` therefore your `Results.jtl` file is being generated in `C:/apache-jmeter-4.0/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin` instead of Jenkins workspace.

So I would recommend to change your command to something like:

```
C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\JMeter\Suite.jmx -l Result.jtl
```

You will also need to **Archive artifacts** via the corresponding post-build action, only this way they will appear on the build dashboard.

[image: JMeter Publish Artifacts]

More information: [Building a software project](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project)

You might also be interested in [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin) which adds Performance Trend chart to the build dashboard and also has possibility of conditionally marking builds as unstable or failed basing on various metrics

[image: JMeter Performance Trend Chart]